# Click and hold on Windows 8 Tablet PC in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8, tablet

I'm converting a reaction time test to tablet PC.  The test involves the user pressing the 5 key on the numeric keypad and holding it down until a random timer fires off and gives them a direction stimulus.  They are then supposed to release the key and press the corresponding direction key (8, 4, 6, 2) and then return to pressing and holding the 5 key.

The problem I'm having is that the tablet treats a long press or press and hold as a right click.  I need to be able to override this behavior. If I put a button on the form with a mousedown and mouseup event, the mousedown event fires properly if I tap-taphold, and then mouseup fires when I release.  but I need a similar event to mousedown for a long press that isn't preparing the tablet for right click.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchdevice.aspx but it isn't available in my version of .net (4) apparently

Comment: Have you referenced PresentationCore.dll in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WinRT-XAML and not WPF, Silverlight or Windows Forms - you could use the `PointerPressed`/`PointerReleased` events instead of the click or gesture events.

Comment: I'm currently using windows forms.  And the app is being converted to tablet, so I'd like to do this with as little reworking as possible.

Comment: I see. Note that Windows Forms apps can't be published to the store.